# retaing docker instance state on launch and not to lose previous session's work

Tags: docker, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a docker image that runs TensorFlow/Keras on my GPU.

I start the session like this which opens a Jupyter Notebook -

```
    sudo systemctl daemon-reload
    sudo systemctl restart docker

    sudo docker run --rm --runtime=nvidia -v -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/
    tensorflow:2.0.0a0-gpu-py3-jupyter
```

The issue is everytime I start it, it will launch a fresh instance and all previous session's work will be lost. How do I maintain the state every time I start it?

Comment: You can mount a hosts volume into the container, which should allow you to retain data between starts. Not sure if that works with sensorflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a container like:

```
sudo docker run --runtime=nvidia -it -v /homepath:/workspace -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:2.0.0a0-gpu-py3-jupyter
```

where /hometpath is the folder that you want to share between your machine and the docker container, /workspace is the path inside the container where /homepath will be copied.

Then after you disconnect you can type :

```
docker attach name
```

where name is a name of a container that you can find by typing:

```
docker container ls
```

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is everytime I start it, it will launch a fresh instance and all previous session's work will be lost. How do I maintain the state every time I start it?

A container is ephemeral...when you call `docker run`, you are creating a *new* container that doesn't inherit any state from previous containers. If you want to maintain data outside the lifecycle of the container, then you use a [docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

You can either allocate a named volume from docker, or [bind-mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) a host directory into your container.

You will need to discover the appropriate path inside the container at which to mount the storage.